# Future prediction using dynlm package in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a data of 39 data points and want to predict the next 3 data pints using the dynlm package..
this is the code i have used for prediction..

```
a <- dynlm(ts(dataUse[,1],freq=12) ~ trend(ts(dataUse[,1],freq=12)) + 
           season(ts(dataUse[,1],freq=12)))
```

can anyone help me in getting the code for predicting next 3 data points..